# i3 + gnome keyring issue

Tags: gnome, 20.04, login, i3-wm, gnome-keyring

I have Ubuntu 20.04 desktop with Gnome. A few months ago I switched to i3, and I like it!

The only issue I have is that when I run some software that needs Gnome Keyring it misbehaves, for example, Google Chrome no longer suggests me my saved passwords..

When I login into i3 (after GDM), I run Seahorse and I see that the Default Keyring is locked. How can I unlock this keyring at i3's startup? Please help.

Answer (score 3):

I assume,

1. your login password is the same to the keyring password
2. libpam-gnome-keyring which provides pam_gnome_keyring.so has been installed.

Then you start gnome-keyring-daemon in ~/.config/i3/config,

```
exec --no-startup-id /usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --start --components=ssh,secrets,pkcs11
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable it, although this disables the security features that it offers or you can start the gnome keyring daemon when logging in.